# Issues updating Docker to version 24.0.7 – missing cli-plugins file causing service startup failure

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-engine

currently have Docker version 20.10.24 and I'm trying to update it to the latest version, 24.0.7. However, the updated version doesn't contain the cli-plugins file, which is causing the Docker service to fail on startup.

Is there an alternative method to update the Docker engine without encountering this issue?

I have replaced the files with the latest version. Upon starting the service , getting this error.

Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Docker Engine (docker)'.
At line:1 char:1

- Start-Service docker
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
  ```

Comment: See Breaking Changes in the release notes : https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/24.0/   Looks like the issue started with a later version of 20.10.  Check following for "plugin" : https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/20.10/